# Error ITMS-90032 Invalid Path

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, application-loader

I changed my iOS app icon, so I updated in Xcode and i just replace the previous icons with the new ones (with the same exactly dimensions). The problem is when I run Application Loader, it shows the following error message:

[image: Error message]

So, I don't know what to do to solve this problem. I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 and Application Loader 3.6

Please, how can I solve this problem.

Comment: The logs messages are saying what you need to do to fix it, add your app icons in your assets.xcassets

Comment: Hi, I have added. I just replace it with the new ones but I don't know why I have this error messages. How can I fix it?